# What episodes are the other doppelgangers in?

Tags: how-i-met-your-mother

In Season 5 Episode 2, *Double Date*, of "How I Met Your Mother", they discover a doppelganger of Lily as a stripper. Narrator Ted mentions that it was the third doppelganger, and then shows clips of a doppelganger for Robin and Marshall. But I don't remember those episodes. Were they actually part of an episode?

Comment: Likely not. They probably developed the whole doppelgänger joke right there and made up those "previous episodes" on the spot.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the Dopplegangers first came up in Season 5 only.

The excert from [Wikia](http://how-i-met-your-mother.wikia.com/wiki/The_Five_Doppelgangers) also confirms this:

> The first doppelgänger shown is Robin's doppelgänger, dubbed "Lesbian Robin" by the group.
>   It is unknown when exactly she was first seen; in Double Date, Future Ted tells his children how earlier he and the group, while walking through New York City, came across a woman who looked exactly like Robin, and due to her appearance named the doppelgänger "Lesbian Robin".
>
> The second doppelgänger is Marshall's doppelgänger, dubbed "Moustache Marshall" by the group.
>   It is unknown when exactly he was first seen; in Double Date, Future Ted tells his children how earlier he and the group came across an advertisement on the back of a bus with a photo of a man who looked exactly like Marshall, and due to his prominent moustache they named the doppelgänger "Moustache Marshall".

Answer (score 2):

All the doppelgangers' first appearances are in Season 5, except for Barney's, who appears in Season 6 Episode 13.

Both Robin, Lily, and Marshall came up in the same episode "Double Date" as Ted is shown in "Robots Versus Wrestlers" and Barney himself in "Bad News".